# SQL query to find table records which are part of same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in optimizing this SQL query.

I have a table called `Student` with the following columns:

`id; Department_Name; Parent_Department`

Values Eg:

```
id  Department_Name Parent_Department
1      IT_CS    
2      IT_BP    
3      IT_NP    
4      IT1                1    
5      IT2                1    
6      IT3                3    
7      IT4      
8      IT9                2
```

My Need is to get all id from table where parent_department = IT_CS;
for this I am writing 2 queries

1. `select id from student where Department_Name ='IT_CS';`
2. `select id from student where parent Parent_Department =Id` fetched from above query;

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like this

```
select id,Department_Name,Parent_Department 
from student as a
inner join student as b on a.parent_Department= b.id
where b.Department_Name='IT_CS'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELF Join statements are devoted for this purpose,

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT S
JOIN STUDENT S1 ON S.PARENT_DEPARTMENT = S1.ID
WHERE S1.DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'IT_CS'
```